# TypeError: publish() takes 2 positional arguments but 3 were given

Tags: python, typeerror, mqtt

So  I am working on a MQTT Publisher and want to create a pub class. 
I found a similar question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43711770/typeerror-function-takes-2-positional-arguments-but-3-were-given), but I do not know how it translates to my problem.

This is my code:

```
def send_on_sensor(q, topic, delay, pub):

    while q.empty is not True:
        payload = json.dumps(q.get())
        pub.publish(payload)
        time.sleep(delay)


class Pub:
    def __init__(self, MQTT_BROKER, MQTT_TOPIC):
        self.MQTT_BROKER = MQTT_BROKER
        self.MQTT_TOPIC = MQTT_TOPIC
        self.mqttc = mqtt.Client()

        self.mqttc.on_connect = self.on_connect
        self.mqttc.publish = self.publish

        # Connect automatically on the creation of the object, but disconnect manually
        self.connect()

    def on_connect(self, client, userdata, flags, rc):
        print("Connecting to {}. Connection returned result: {}".format(self.MQTT_BROKER, rc))
        self.mqttc.subscribe(self.MQTT_TOPIC)

    def publish(self, MQTT_MSG):
        self.mqttc.publish(self.MQTT_TOPIC, MQTT_MSG)

    def connect(self):
        self.mqttc.connect(self.MQTT_BROKER)

    def disconnect(self):
        self.mqttc.disconnect()
```

I get this error:

```
Exception in thread Thread-4:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.7/lib/python3.7/threading.py", line 917, in _bootstrap_inner
    self.run()
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.7/lib/python3.7/threading.py", line 865, in run
    self._target(*self._args, **self._kwargs)
  File "/Users//PycharmProjects//V3_multiTops/mt_GenPub.py", line 76, in send_on_sensor
    pub.publish(payload)
  File "/Users//PycharmProjects//V3_multiTops/mt_GenPub.py", line 129, in publish
    self.mqttc.publish(self.MQTT_TOPIC, MQTT_MSG)
TypeError: publish() takes 2 positional arguments but 3 were given
```

What exactly is the problem here and how do I fix it?

Comment: the publish method seems to be recursive and calling itself

Comment: try removing the line self.mqttc.publish = self.publish. And, rename the def publish to def update. publish is a method as part of MQTT client, so better not to use that name.

Comment: removing  `self.mqttc.publish = self.update` fixed the issue. But why is that the case?

Comment: is the message getting published now?

Comment: yes, I just understood that I do not actually want to attach a routine, but rather use a method of `mqttc`

Comment: there is a publish method already as part of MQTT and you were creating a new publish method in your code and recursing it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're passing two arguments to publish():

```
self.mqttc.publish(self.MQTT_TOPIC, MQTT_MSG)
```

But the function was defined to only take one argument (aside from `self`, which is passed automatically):

```
def publish(self, MQTT_MSG):
```

Why are you passing `MQTT_TOPIC`?